# Guardar fecha en MySQL en c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

Estoy realizando un proyectoABC en Windows Forms mediante visual studio, y después de varios formularios necesito guardar la fecha, sin embargo, al momento de realizar el guardado la conexión no se realiza de forma exitosa (la conexion me funciona correctamente con otros formularios que no requieren la fecha), el código es el siguiente:

```
private void btn_Guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (alDAO.Agregar(RecuperarInformacion()) == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Registro Agregado");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Algo salio mal");
        }
        //Actualiza el grid
        dtg_Vista.DataSource = alDAO.Buscar();
        limpiarcontroles();
    }

public int Agregar(Cls_AlumnosBO alBO)
    {
        //se sustituyen los números por los valores de las variables
        string ComandoSQL = string.Format("INSERT INTO alumno (matricula, nombre, apellido, id_div, fecha_nac)VALUES({0}, '{1}', '{2}', {3}, {4});", alBO.Matricula, alBO.Nombre, alBO.Apellido, alBO.Id_div, alBO.Fecha_nac);
        return MiConexion.EjecutarComando(ComandoSQL);
    }
private Cls_AlumnosBO RecuperarInformacion()
    {
        //Se recupera informacion del formulario
        //crea un objeto de la clase productos bo
        alBO = new Cls_AlumnosBO();
        alBO.Matricula = Convert.ToInt32(txt_matricula.Text);
        alBO.Nombre = txt_Nombre.Text;
        alBO.Apellido = txt_Apellido.Text;
        alBO.Fecha_nac = Convert.ToDateTime(dt_Fecha.Text);
        alBO.Id_div = Convert.ToInt32(cmb_Division.SelectedValue);

        return alBO;
    }
```

Comment: cual es el error exacto que te aparece?

Comment: Mi problema que tal vez no especifique bien es que no sé si hay alguna manera especifica de guardar la fecha, pues, la conexion se realiza normalmente, pero no me acepta el formato de la fecha como la estoy enviando, disculpa, no tengo mucha experiancia con BD, el problema recae realmente en el ***"INSERT INTO alumno (matricula, nombre, apellido, id_div, fecha_nac)VALUES({0}, '{1}', '{2}', {3}, {4});"***

Comment: el tipo de dato para guardar fechas en MySQL es DATE que lo guarda en formato YYYY-MM-DD; quiere decir que si tu declaraste en tu base de datos que ese tipo de dato sea DATE pero desde tu formulario envias una estructura de dato distinta por eso te lo esta rechazando

Comment: En la base de datos tengo declarado el atributo como datetime, y de igual manera estoy enviando el atributo como datetime, el problema que se me dificulta explicar sería la estructura del envio de datos, donde por ejemplo, cuando envio datos de valor numerico hago algo como (matricula)VALUES(***{}***) y en el caso de valores de texto uso las comillas simples, por ejemplo (nombre)VALUES(***'{}'***), pero no sé si deba utilizar otro tipo de carácteres para enviar la fecha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error está en esta línea

```
string ComandoSQL = string.Format("INSERT INTO alumno (matricula, nombre, apellido, id_div, fecha_nac)VALUES({0}, '{1}', '{2}', {3}, {4});", alBO.Matricula, alBO.Nombre, alBO.Apellido, alBO.Id_div, alBO.Fecha_nac);
```

Esto hace que internamente se llame a [DateTime.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.110).aspx), que dice lo siguiente:

> Convierte el valor del objeto DateTime actual en su representación de
>   cadena equivalente usando las convenciones de formato de la referencia
>   cultural actual.

En el mío genera lo siguiente:

```
3/11/2018 3:59:31 AM
```

Lo que significa que depende de lo que tu programa esté usando como [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/es/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), lo cual por lo general está basado en las opciones de tu sistema.

Lo más fácil sería que resolvieras usando el método [ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) que acepta un formato para convertir la fecha a una cadena de carácteres aceptada por mysql como está descrito en los comentarios. **Sin embargo te recomiendo que no envíes directamente las cadenas en tus consultas si no que uses instrucciones parametrizadas para reducir las posibilidades de sufrir por problemas de inyección SQL.**

Comment: Gracias, ya pude solucionar el problema, tarde un poco en contestar debido a que me quede sin internet unos dias, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si la respuesta te fue de utilidad considera votar y aceptarla.